# Poem in one of B.T. Narros books but cannot remember which one

Tags: story-identification, books

In one of the books I believe in the Rhythm of Rivalry series by B. T. Narro there is a poem or story about having a soldier around and not wanting them unless there was a need for them to be fighting or killing. I cannot remember which book it was in. Was hoping someone knows or highlighted it.

Comment: Was it an original poem, or was the author quoting Kipling's ["Tommy"](https://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/tommy.html)?

Comment: It was similar to that one but not that one, I believe it was original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first book of the series, Bastial Energy, chapter 57:

> Effie found herself wishing Cleve was still in Kyrro. She’d never met someone she could tell was reliable even without yet needing to rely on him. It reminded her of a poem she’d memorized long ago.
>   
>   I knew a warrior. He smelled of shit.
>   Skilled with sword but had no wit.
>   He never let me be alone.
>   Said I couldn’t be on my own.
>   You are too beautiful, he would say
>   Trouble will come to you one day.
>   I’ll take my chances, go away.
>   You are the source of my dismay.
>   With that he left, and all was good,
>   Until a man came masked in hood.
>   He stole my money and broke my bones.
>   No one was there to heed my groans.
>   I realized then what I know today
>   Which to you I will convey.
>   A warrior’s kiss is never missed,
>   Eventually he’ll get the clue.
>   But in his fist that you dismissed,
>   Was a sword protecting you